# how to read properties file in scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala programming and I wanted to read a properties file in Scala.

I can't find any APIs to read a property file in Scala.

Please let me know if there are any API for this or other way to read properties files in Scala.

Answer (score 23):

Beside form Java API, there is a library by Typesafe called [config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) with a good API for working with configuration files of different types.

Comment: Too complicated, and reads resources rather than files :(

Comment: Please do not suggest people to refer to over-engineered libraries like TypeSafe config when they can simply use java API from scala. I know Type-Safe config has its pros and cons but why use a tunnel boring machine to drill in the wall?

Answer (score 18):

You will have to do it in similar way you would with with Scala `Map` to `java.util.Map`. `java.util.Properties` extends `java.util.HashTable` whiche extends `java.util.Dictionary`.

`scala.collection.JavaConverters` has functions to convert to and fro from `Dictionary` to Scala `mutable.Map`:

```
val x = new Properties
//load from .properties file here.
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> x.asScala
res4: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String] = Map()
```

You can then use `Map` above. To get and retrieve. But if you wish to convert it back to `Properties` type (to store back etc), you might have to type cast it manually then.

Answer (score 7):

You can just use the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Answer (score 2):

Consider something along the lines

```
def getPropertyX: Option[String] = Source.fromFile(fileName)
  .getLines()
  .find(_.startsWith("propertyX="))
  .map(_.replace("propertyX=", ""))
```

Comment: Use Property instead

```val properties = new Properties
properties.load(this.getClass.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/file.properties"))```