# Scala SBT Project Application Configuration File

Tags: scala, sbt, configuration-files

I come from the C# .NET world and as I build my Scala project I noticed how many different ways there are to do things in the open source community. Anyways in .Net C# project we have the `Web.config` or the `App.config` file which is very useful to specify app keys that are used globally and it is also helpful for transformation for different environments and such.

What would be the equivalent for a Scala SBT project? Do you know a place to store your connection strings and other app settings?

Answer (score 8):

There is no universal configuration file name. The basic way is to use `Properties`, see e.g. [how to read properties file in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873162/how-to-read-properties-file-in-scala), and call the file `your-application-name.properties`. But there is a popular library called simply [Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) which I'd recommend; as https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior says, its standard names for config files are

> The convenience method  ConfigFactory.load()  loads the following (first-listed are higher priority):
>
> - system properties
> - application.conf  (all resources on classpath with this name)
> - application.json  (all resources on classpath with this name)
> - application.properties  (all resources on classpath with this name)
> - reference.conf  (all resources on classpath with this name)
>
> The idea is that libraries and frameworks should ship with a  reference.conf  in their jar. Applications should provide an  application.conf , or if they want to create multiple configurations in a single JVM, they could use  ConfigFactory.load("myapp")  to load their own  myapp.conf . (Applications can provide a  reference.conf  also if they want, but you may not find it necessary to separate it from  application.conf .)

As @ashalynd's answer says, in order for any such library to see your configuration files, they should go into `src/{main,test}/resources`.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are talking about `application.conf`. It can be found in `/src/main/resources` or in `/src/test/resources` (affecting main and test settings, respectively). If `application.conf` is not present in `/src/test/resources`, the main `application.conf` will be used for the tests.

Comment: Yes! the only thing is that my resource directory is empty and right clicking and selecting "new" in the context menu of intelliJ doesn't give me the option to add a config file. so I what the right way to add the configuration file is or if i should just brute force create it. I'm a total noob in intelliJ scala

Comment: Just brute force create it.